# Access GreenDAO generator project dynamically from Android project

Tags: android, greendao

Is it possible, from an Android project using GreenDAO, to dynamically (at run-time) access database model structural information (entities, properties, Schema, ...) defined in the generator project?

My first impression is that it's not possible. If it is, how can I do that?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can do via reflection.

`DaoMaster`'s parent, `AbstractDaoMaster` has a private field `daoConfigMap` which includes the configuration for tables.

not a proper way but possible if you are trying to hack sth.

Another approach, if you want to access properties on know dao's etc, each generated `Dao` class have a public static `Properties` class which defines the properties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does `daoConfigMap` also includes configuration about relations? I suppose it does. 
It's for determining whether I could do some dynamic reconfiguration of the database model for one of my works.

Comment: @yigit, Do you think with this approach it's possible to make and use dynamic DAO objects (objects whose SQL layout is created at run time not at compile time)?